# Where does the AT-ACT door go?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the question '[Why does one AT-AT have a hole in it in “Rogue One”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151503/why-does-one-at-at-have-a-hole-in-it-in-rogue-one)' I learned about the AT-ACT, and also that the orange doors open and close.

As we can see in the following picture the closest AT-ACT has its doors shut and they take up a lot of the space of the back of the vehicle. The far away AT-ACT has its doors open but the main section of the doors are nowhere to be seen. With the size of them it seems like we should be able to see at least part of them.

[image: Scarif battle]

Where do the doors go when they are open?

Comment: I'd assume you slot the cargo pallet in directly. And that the doors are part of the pallet, rather than part of the AT-ACT

Comment: @Valorum - Like a horizontal Thunderbird 2?  Seems reasonable.  Or the doors could be back in the hangar.

Comment: @Valorum you may be on to something, kinda like how we have shipping containers that go from truck to train to ship back to truck without having to move the contents of the container.

Comment: oh, cool! you mentioned my question. thanks :-)

Comment: It may make sense for them to be detachable, as in cargo too big to fit inside, but not too heavy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I believe the doors on the AT-ACT above are open, only obscured by the camera angle.**

It appears as if the "doors" are really just small panels that hold the cargo in and, as such, may not entirely enclose the cargo space (with or without cargo). The cargo-less AT-ACT appears to be at an angle where the top door panel seems almost flush with the top of the Walker, while the bottom panel does seem visible. Please see attached graphic.

[image]

Comment: Is this a licensed toy?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It is a Disney branded product. As to canonicity beyond that, I'm not sure how to determine veracity.

Answer (score 6):

This concept art seems to suggest the the cargo bay doors hinge split horizontally in the middle, with the lower portion simply hanging loose and with the upper piece folding upwards. Given their notable absence in your picture, it seems most likely that they're also detachable and are removed when not needed.

[image]

Comment: Good find seems your assumption was correct. How canon is concept art?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - Concept art (and indeed, all 'making-of stuff) is considered to be non-canon (e.g. "Legends").

Comment: I thought as much, this is probably the answer though even if we don't have anything more canon

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - The [licensed toys](http://www.very.co.uk/star-wars-rogue-one-rapid-fire-imperial-at-act/1600105788.prd?sku=sku19622573&cm_mmc=google-_-PLA+-+Toys+%26+Games-_-Toys+%26+Games+-+Toys+-+Generic-_-na_85148722378&utm_medium=cpc&k_clickid=6d3b6445-0531-41e8-ad80-ff87af683441&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Shopping_Toys%20&%20Games&utm_term=na&utm_content=85148722378&profileid=402&keywordid=na&productgroupid=pg287015&device=c&gclid=Cj0KEQiAiMHEBRC034nx2ImB1J0BEiQA-r7ctqS40oqzTnZo0CMj7CtG8k8CqD3hxc4AWn5F486JOTwaAhVp8P8HAQ) aren't much help. They also have hinged doors

Comment: I was just looking into them! Although that one you linked to does come with a container type thing